# ERROR in ./src/App.jsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/Footer'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a react-app change to SSR using Koa.
but can't resolve folder.  It works well in CSR....

> **ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/Footer' in '/mnt/c/Users/moidp/CloudStation/sangwook/Programing/project/blog/blog-frontend/src'
>    @ ./src/App.jsx 18:0-40 129:27-33`enter code here`
>    @ ./src/ssr/render.js
>
> ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/NavBar' in '/mnt/c/Users/moidp/CloudStation/sangwook/Programing/project/blog/blog-frontend/src'
>    @ ./src/App.jsx 17:0-40 105:25-31
>    @ ./src/ssr/render.js**

webpack.config.server.js

```
'use strict';

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const paths = require('./paths');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');

const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

const publicUrl = paths.servedPath.slice(0, -1);
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production', // 프로덕션 모드로 설정하여 최적화 옵션들을 활성화
  entry: paths.serverRenderJs, // 엔트리 경로
  target: 'node', // node 환경에서 실행 될 것이라는 것을 명시
  output: {
    path: paths.ssrBuild, // 빌드 경로
    filename: 'server.js', // 파일이름
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].chunk.js', // 청크 파일이름
    publicPath: paths.servedPath, // 정적 파일이 제공 될 경로
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        oneOf: [
          // 자바스크립트를 위한 처리
          // 기존 webpack.config.js 를 참고하여 작성
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              customize: require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'),
              plugins: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                  {
                    loaderMap: {
                      svg: {
                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo![path]',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,
              compact: false,
            },
          },
          // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
          // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              configFile: false,
              compact: false,
              presets: [
                [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'), { helpers: true }],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
              cacheCompression: false,

              // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
              // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
              // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
              // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
              sourceMaps: false,
            },
          },
          // CSS 를 위한 처리
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
            //  onlyLocals: true 옵션을 설정해야 실제 css 파일을 생성하지 않습니다.
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              onlyLocals: true,
            },
          },
          // CSS Module 을 위한 처리
          {
            test: cssModuleRegex,
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              modules: true,
              onlyLocals: true,
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            },
          },
          // Sass 를 위한 처리
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            use: [
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  onlyLocals: true,
                },
              },
              require.resolve('sass-loader'),
            ],
          },
          // Sass + CSS Module 을 위한 처리
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            use: [
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  onlyLocals: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              },
              require.resolve('sass-loader'),
            ],
          },
          // url-loader 를 위한 설정
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              emitFile: false, // 파일을 따로 저장하지 않는 옵션
              limit: 10000, // 원래는 9.76KB가 넘어가면 파일로 저장하는데
              // emitFile 값이 false 일땐 경로만 준비하고 파일은 저장하지 않습니다.
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // 위에서 설정된 확장자를 제외한 파일들은
          // file-loader 를 사용합니다.
          {
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            options: {
              emitFile: false, // 파일을 따로 저장하지 않는 옵션
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified), // 환경변수를 주입해줍니다.
  ],
};
```

on App.jsx

```
import { Home, Editor, Post, About, Auth } from './pages';
import NavBar from './component/NavBar';
import Footer from './component/Footer';
```

path.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
// https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/637
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = (relativePath) => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

const envPublicUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

function ensureSlash(inputPath, needsSlash) {
  const hasSlash = inputPath.endsWith('/');
  if (hasSlash && !needsSlash) {
    return inputPath.substr(0, inputPath.length - 1);
  } if (!hasSlash && needsSlash) {
    return `${inputPath}/`;
  } 
    return inputPath;

}

const getPublicUrl = (appPackageJson) => envPublicUrl || require(appPackageJson).homepage;

// We use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable or "homepage" field to infer
// "public path" at which the app is served.
// Webpack needs to know it to put the right <script> hrefs into HTML even in
// single-page apps that may serve index.html for nested URLs like /todos/42.
// We can't use a relative path in HTML because we don't want to load something
// like /todos/42/static/js/bundle.7289d.js. We have to know the root.
function getServedPath(appPackageJson) {
  const publicUrl = getPublicUrl(appPackageJson);
  const servedUrl = envPublicUrl || (publicUrl ? url.parse(publicUrl).pathname : '/');
  return ensureSlash(servedUrl, true);
}

const moduleFileExtensions = [
  'web.mjs',
  'mjs',
  'web.js',
  'js',
  'web.ts',
  'ts',
  'web.tsx',
  'tsx',
  'json',
  'web.jsx',
  'jsx',
];

// Resolve file paths in the same order as webpack
const resolveModule = (resolveFn, filePath) => {
  const extension = moduleFileExtensions.find((extension) =>
    fs.existsSync(resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`)),
  );

  if (extension) {
    return resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`);
  }

  return resolveFn(`${filePath}.js`);
};

// config after eject: we're in ./config/
module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appPath: resolveApp('.'),
  appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
  appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
  proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  publicUrl: getPublicUrl(resolveApp('package.json')),
  servedPath: getServedPath(resolveApp('package.json')),
  serverRendenJs: resolveApp('src/server/render.js'),
  server: resolveApp('server/render'),
};

module.exports.moduleFileExtensions = moduleFileExtensions;
```

Comment: Can you show us your `paths.js` file?

Comment: sure, i add it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems webpack might not know how to resolve the `.jsx` file extensions for your `/Footer.jsx` and `/NavBar.jsx` files.

This problem might be solved by adding `.jsx` to `resolve.extensions` like so:

```js
resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', ...]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

check your package.json and you can try this;

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not imported the correct path to Footer and NavBar components in your App.jsx file and you're trying to render those two incorrectly imported components in App.jsx.
Can you please share your complete App.jsx file and the folder structure of your project to pinpoint the error better.

Comment: It works well in client rendering. but when build for serverside rendering is not work. App.jsx is just routing to each componts.

Comment: your webpack has all the dependencies to bundle but have you installed all babel packages to transpile? Node.js code needs to be transpiled by Babel, as server-side Node.js code does not know anything about JSX, nor ES Modules

Comment: Like you said, there seems to be a problem at the Babel. I have changed "pages/index.jsx -> index.js", so remove error from related pages. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Can you add these dependencies to your server code @babel/register @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react. After that add the following snippet in the entry point
  `require('@babel/register')({
       ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
  })`
after this require in your other files.
Hope this helps